# How to override link click in TextView to add an action

Tags: android, textview, clickablespan, linkmovementmethod

There is text with HTML tags. Following instructions from other answers, I formatted the text with HtmlCompat and added ClickableSpan and LinkMovementMethod. However, when I click on the link, I only follow it, and the additional actions that I defined inside onClick() are not performed. What should I do?

```
                val linkText = notification.description.substringBeforeLast("</a>")
                    .substringAfterLast("\">")
                val str = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
                    notification.description,
                    HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT
                ) as SpannableStringBuilder
                val start = str.indexOf(linkText, ignoreCase = true)
                str.setSpan(
                    object : ClickableSpan() {
                        override fun updateDrawState(ds: TextPaint) {
                            ds.color = ds.linkColor
                            ds.isUnderlineText = true
                        }
                        override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                            Selection.setSelection((widget as TextView).text as Spannable, 0)
                            widget.invalidate()
                            listener.onClick(notification.id)
                        }
                    },
                    start,
                    start + linkText.length - 1,
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                )
                tvDescription.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
                tvDescription.setText(str, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

So, the code that I wrote inside this function onClick() is simply not called. I checked it in debug mode. However, the link is followed.